# reverseGeocodeLocation's completion Handler not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, reversegeocodelocation

I have written my code to get the current location of the user as follows-

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations{
CLLocation *currentLocation=[locations lastObject];
if (currentLocation!=nil) {
    _cityTextField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    _locationTextField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
}

[geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray<CLPlacemark *> *placeMarks, NSError *error){
    if (error==nil && [placeMarks count]>0) {
        placeMark=[placeMarks lastObject];
        _cityTextField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",placeMark.administrativeArea];
        _locationTextField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",placeMark.locality];
        [location stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"%@",error.debugDescription);
    }
}];
```

I am able to get the value of latitude and longitude in my text fields.But when the pointer reaches reverseGeocodeLocation method, it does not execute the completion handler and directly reaches at the end. Can anyone please point out my mistake. Thanks

Comment: That is quite usual. The completion handler will be called later (if at all). 

Set a breakpoint within the handler.

Comment: @HermannKlecker I did as you told me to do, but it did not work. Completion hadler is not getting called at all.

Comment: Then the reverse geo location did not work. Meaning no location was found.

Comment: `geoCoder` might be null. Did you check that?

Comment: I can see that location is found, because I have filled the cityTextField and locationTextField with latitude and longitude of currentLocation, and i can see them in the output. The only problem is that i am not able to convert them in human understandable form using CLGeoCoder.

Comment: @HermannKlecker  you are right. It show the geocoder and placeMark nil. I made a silly mistake, I forgot to initialise the geocoder and placemark. I initialised them and able to call the completion handler. But I am getting a bad_access_error now.

Comment: No need to initialize placemark but geocoder of course.

Comment: Where exactly do you get the bad_access?

Comment: @aman_kumar_aggarwal please provide your answer as an answer instead of editing the question.

Comment: placeMark=[placeMarks lastObject];
At this point.

Comment: Interesting. How is placeMark declared? 
What happens when you do `CLPlacemark * localPlaceMark = [placeMarks lastObject]` instead?

Comment: @HermannKlecker Thanks a lot Hermann. It worked. I guess I need to study more about memory management. Thanks for the help. Where can I accept your answer?

Comment: There are some things to consider when using blocks. Your completion handler is a block which is executed at a later point in time. Local variables can be difficult there. Read about blocks.